# What causes Javascript to act differently on different machines?

Tags: javascript

I just added a feature to a forum and while most users see and use it, a small number of people report strange behavior. I thought the problem might be due to browser caching and a ctrl+F5 solved it for some, but some can't fix it. (It's a simple editor button.)

I feel stupid even asking this but is there any way JS could not work on some machines the way it should?

EDIT: code added:

```
    insertTab: function()
{
    if( this.get_selection() == "" )
    {
            var val = prompt( "How many lines of tablature?", '');
            if( val == '' ) return true;

            val = parseInt(val);

            var txt = "[code]\n";

            while ( val > 0 )
            {
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n";
                txt += "\n";

                val--;
            }

            this.insert_text( txt + "[/code]" );
    }
    else
    {
        this.wrap_tags_lite( '[code]', '[/code]', 0);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on every computer I've tried personally.

Comment: Please add the offending code.

Comment: *Most* JavaScript (properly written) *does* behave the same, and it's more of a browser difference than a machine difference (OS I mean), you should post the code and which browsers are having issues.

Comment: Please clarify "but some can't fix it." Does this mean, that some don't see the button?

Comment: If Ctrl+F5 fixes it for "some" but not "all" users, are you *100% sure* those who say they're doing a "force refresh" are actually doing it? I've have plenty of users swear left-and-right that they're doing what I tell them to do only to find out that they're actually not doing it at all... In that case, you can try adding a dummy query string to your css file - this'll force all browsers to reload it (regardless of caching policy, since it "looks like" a whole new URL) like: `href="my.css?v=1234"`.

Comment: They see the button, but they don't get the desired result when they click it. It changes the fonts settings instead.

Comment: @mathon12 - Is `get_selection()` getting the selected text? This is *definitely* non-standard, and you'll need to handle different browsers in different ways.

Comment: @Nick- yup. When I have text selected it wraps the [code] tags around it. Tried it on FF, Chrome, IE and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its not really the machines that is causing the problem, most likely it is the browsers. Javascript runtime engines are implemented a little bit differently in all of the browsers so you can get slightly different behavior out of each.

IE, WebKit, and Mozilla all behave a little bit differently. When you are testing your code, you need to test on all browsers. Another option is to use a library like JQuery which somewhat abstracts some of the nuances out of javascript cross-browser programming.

Comment: This is the best general answer but if they post the code we may be able to drill down to a specific solution.

Comment: This makes browser scripting sound like black magic, which it really isn't.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought first. But it really wouldn't surprise me if some of the users just forgot to turn on JS on their browsers. >.< Added the offending code.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is specifically for addressing the cache issue, I can't say much on the "other" behavior without seeing the code.*

When you change your script, either in an automated build process (if at all possible) or manually, you can update your script references, for example look at this page (I removed `type=""` for brevity)

```
<script src="http://sstatic.net/js/master.js?v=ad53a2ffc630"></script>
```

It used to be a number, the changeset of the checkin or something, I'm not sure of the source, and it doesn't matter really, as long as it updated when the build changes.  I assume it's some sort of hash now, which is even smarter, users won't re-download it on a version change if *that* file didn't change.

The important part is that it *does* change when the file does, and because of the querystring the browser will re-download the file, eliminating the need for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Okay, so a difference in parameter values should force a re-download. However the format I'm dealing with is like src=".../ipb.js?load=lang,editor" so I can't directly reference ipb.editor.js, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: @mathon12 - You can add another parameter, or should be able to, it depends what that loader does, but `&v=something` on the end should work.